# Magento: how to get country name for xtendo order export xsl template

Tags: php, xslt, magento-1.7

I am referring to Xtendo Order Export ext [here](http://support.xtento.com/wiki/Magento_Extensions%3aMagento_Order_Export_Module). I know that this is the snippet to get country code

```
<xsl:value-of select="shipping/country_id"/>
```

My requirement is to fetch country name which in Magento is

```
Mage::getModel('directory/country')->load($country_code)->getName();
```

But in xsl how to call above getName() method

Hey genius guys plz help me find right way:

```
<xsl:value-of select="php:functionString('Mage_Directory_Model_Country::load', shipping/country_id)"/>
```

Something like this..... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In recent versions of the extension (that is any version since December 2012) you would retrieve it like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="shipping/country_name"/>
```

For older versions, this field was not available without customizations and you should upgrade the extension. Go to www.xtento.com and click on XTENTO > My Downloads.